# What is the geometrical meaning of the integral of a vector valued function?

Tags: calculus, integration, differential-geometry, vector-spaces, contour-integration

If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is an integrable function.

then $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ can be considered as the area between the graph and the x-axis.

But what if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$?

Let $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth curve.

what is the **geometrical** meaning of $\int_\gamma f\cdot dl$? (or in case $n=m$, $= \int_0^1 f(\gamma(t))\gamma '(t)\cdot dt$?)

Thanks :)

(for simplicity, you can assume $m,n$ are small numbers... i.e $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ )

Comment: Well, it's a vector. Isn't a vector a geometrical object?

Comment: Hope I  made it clearer :) I mean the line/contour integral of a vector valued function

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_vector_field) has a neat animation that you should look at.

Comment: @Daniel What does $f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)$ mean?  Do you mean $f(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma'(t)$?  If so, then $n=m$.

Comment: I would like to interject that if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ where $n\neq m$ then $\int_0^1f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\ dt$ does not make sense, as $f$ is $\mathbb{R}^m$ valued while $\gamma'$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$ valued. Also OP's wording makes me think he wants to do a **vector valued** integral, not a usual line integral.

Comment: I don't a have a geometrical meaning, but I can relate it to physics.  f(x) represents a force you may be working with the force, or against the force.  The path integral represents the amount of energy that will be expended (or released) traveling between the endpoints.  If f(x) is a conservative force (like gravity) then the energy you expend going up hill, you get back when you go down hill, and the choice of path does not matter, only the endpoints matter.

Answer (score 2):

There is another common interpretation of integration that you might be familiar with, which is an interpretation of a *continuous sum*. In case you aren't familiar with this, I'll explain it in terms of the area interpretation.

If you imagine drawing the curve $y=f(x)$, the area under the curve can be roughly interpreted as the sum of all the infinitesimal-width vertical 'strips' which connect the point $(x,0)$ to the point $(x,f(x))$. Of course, this doesn't make *much* sense, because there's no such thing as a rectangle with 'infinitely small width'. One way of turning this intuitive picture into a sensible idea is the *Riemann sums*, which are roughly of the form:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{i}^{*})(x_{i+1}-x_{i})$$
where $x_{0},\ldots,x_{n}$ are points that partition your interval $[a,b]$ into the intervals $[x_{i-1},x_{i}]$, and $x_{i}^{*}$ is some point in that interval. But this can also be viewed as a *weighted sum* of the values $f$ takes in the interval $[a,b]$. If we take a suitable limit of the partition which makes the intervals $[x_{i-1},x_{i}]$ uniformly small, we get your area interpretation of the integral.

So, the line integral $$\int_{\gamma}f(x)dx:=\int_{a}^{b}f(\gamma(t))|\gamma'(t)|dt$$
can be interpreted as a continuous sum of *vector contributions* of $f$, as we travel along small portions of the curve $\gamma$. The $|\gamma'(t)|$ factor, reminiscent of the substitution rule for 1-D integrals, can be thought of as a scale factor relating how 'fast' we go along the curve $\gamma$ - this ensures that if we reparametrise the curve so that we go faster or slower in places, we don't change the value of the integral.

For a *physical* example, let's suppose $\gamma$ is a uniformly charged wire, and you want to calculate the electric field at a point $x$ due the wire. Well, there is a charge contribution from each point $\gamma(t)$, which is given approximately by $\lambda |\gamma'(t)|dt|$, where we have written $\lambda$ for the charge per unit length of the wire. The electric field due to this point-like charge is simply $$E(\gamma(t))=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{x-\gamma(t)}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}|x-\gamma(t)|^{3}}\lambda|\gamma'(t)|dt = \int_{\gamma}\frac{x-x'}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}|x-x'|^{3}}\lambda dx'$$

I hope that's a satisfying example - if you haven't seen much electromagnetism then it probably won't make much sense, but electric fields are the simplest example I can think of of a meaningful vector-valued line integral. If you don't insist on the integrand being vector valued, then the work done on a point particle is probably a simpler and more intuitive example.